# git config email address correct, but magit commit email address does not match

Tags: git, github, commit, magit

Magit works fine for me, no commit fails, but my commit email address is not correct in magit. If i check git config the correct email address appears, but each new commit I make using magit, by default, has this email: `blah@blahs-MacBook-Pro.local` (i'm using a mac)

How can I fix the magit commit email address?

Comment: How did you configure the email address using git?

Comment: I set the git commit email address with `git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Comment: And you have verified that for the same repository, git and magit behaves differently? If so then the only logical conclusion is that magit uses an email address configured somewhere else.

Comment: Does `magit` run with its own username, which is different from the username by which you log on?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes git and magit behave differently. That is likely the logical conclusion but I cannot find where that other email address is configured.

Comment: @ElpieKayI I'm not sure I understand the question. Magit's author name is correct but the email is incorrect. I'm not sure what a magit username might, or how to even check what it is. ...I am new to magit...

Comment: Have you checked if Magit have set email in the local config of the repo? `git config --local --list`. Local config overrides global config

Comment: @crea1 I've just checked using that line, it looks like there is no email address set locally.